# Issue with drawing half of a sphere in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a skydome in three.js like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 40, 32, 15, 1*Math.PI/2, 2*Math.PI, Math.PI, Math.PI);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xddddff } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
scene.add( mesh );
```

This does draw half of a sphere but it also colors the part that I expected to be open (it colors the surface of my mesh that I need the skydome for). How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't drawing the sphere correctly:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 60, 60, Math.PI, Math.PI, 3*Math.PI/2);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xddddff } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The thing is that even if you draw half a sphere, I doubt it will put UVs correctly, so I very recommend you to make your own skydome using custom mesh.
2. For skydome you can use **mesh.material.side = THREE.BackSide** instead of .DoubleSide, btw, unless you stay on the surface all the time.

Comment: 1. As you can see I am creating custom mesh using a sphere for my geometry. The question is why it closes the bottom part, instead of leaving it open.
2. I want to use THREE.DoubleSide